# Unicode Subscript Zero Android

Tags: android-studio, unicode

Good evening. What is wrong with this damn zero? Used Unicode & # 8320 ;. The row is loaded from the database. The rest of the characters are fine. The picture shows.

[image: unic]

Comment: I'm not sure I can see what the problem is.

Comment: On API 19, Unicode subscript 0 is displayed as a regular zero.